# How to change the button colour after playing animation in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change colour of button after playing animation for some time. What I have searched and found that, it needs to change a new frame. Here is my CSS:

```css
.header-button {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fbd3cc;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline;
  background: #026890;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.animate-flicker {
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s infinite alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: 10;
  -moz-animation-name: changecolor;
}

@keyframes changecolor {
  {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="header-button animate-flicker">Menue
</button>
```

Can some one tell me how i can change the button colour after playing animation for 5 times in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make both animations either:

- In the same keyframes

```
@keyframes fadeInNColor {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

- or call each of them from the same rule

```
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s infinite alternate, changecolor 0.5s  infinite alternate forwards;
```

```css
.header-button {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fbd3cc;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #026890;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.animate-flicker {
  animation: 
    fadeIn 0.5s infinite alternate, /* first animation*/
    changecolor 0.5s  infinite alternate forwards;/* second animation freezed */
  animation-iteration-count: 5;
}

@keyframes changecolor {
  to {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="header-button animate-flicker">Menue
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a span into the button tag and apply the color change to the span by delaying it by a few seconds to finish the nimation

Comment: This is an extra work to do like this way. I have seen somewhere there is a possibility in css to do this..

Comment: I think it's not possible to apply two animations on the same item. if possible, we will learn a new trick following your issue ;)

Comment: Just gave it a go on codepen, I was not able to apply two animations to the same element. So I'd agree with this answer. Simply wrap it in another element, and trigger your animation on this after a set delay.

Comment: @Mahmoud Have a look at G-Cyr's answer; Apparently it is possible to apply two animations on the same item;

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
@keyframes changecolor
{
 to {background:red;}
}
```

Comment: Sorry this is not changing colour after finish animation.